# use json format in an URL

Tags: asp.net, json, angularjs

I am building a rest API with asp.net my problem is that when I try to add a student to my database like that :

http://localhost:50001/api/Students?&FirstName=cc&LastName=cc&Email=student10@gmail.com&DropOut=false&Live=false&ClassId=1&ImageId=1

I get "the value variable is null",
this is my code to add a student:

```
      // Get All Students
        [Route("api/Students")]
        public IEnumerable<Student> Get()
        {
            return _StudentService.Queryable().ToList();
        }
// Insert Student
[Route("api/Students/")]
public IEnumerable<Student> Post(Student value)
        {
              cc.Students.Add(value);
                    cc.SaveChanges();
                    return Get();
   }
```

I have used "Fiddler web Debugger" to test my URLs an it works only in this way:

[image]

now If I have an angularJS client that tries to add a new student to the database,how can I send data as a json format in an URL

this is how I add a new student from my client angularJS:

```
$http({method: 'POST', url: 'http://localhost:50001/api/Students?&FirstName=cc&LastName=cc&Email=student10@gmail.com&DropOut=false&Live=false&ClassId=1&ImageId=1})

                 .success(function (data) {
                     console.log("success");

         }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {

                     console.log("data error ...");
                            });
```

thanks a lot for help

Comment: If you need to send data in a JSON format, why not use POST? Otherwise, you can use JSON.stringify().

Comment: ok @jason9187 thanks I will test JSON.stringify() because I already use POST in my angularJS client

Comment: But if you stringify the contents, then you'll just have to parse it back out on the back end. I would suggest you stick with POST.

Comment: ok jason thanks  a lot :)

Answer (score 3):

If you are saying you want a true Rest API you should continue to use the POST verb as it is more semantically right for creating a new student.

Passing a new student on the URL is possible but not in the configuration you have provided.
Your API method expects a POST request and that the new student be located in the HTTP body.

Just configure your angular call to use jsonData and post it to your API.